# Javascript .match() not working when using /gi flags

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

When using `.match` function on a string `html`, the following code returns an array with the matches.

```
    html = '<span><b>123</b>C / <b>456</b>K</span>'
    var matches = html.match('<span><b>(.*?)</b>C / <b>(.*?)</b>K</span>')
    console.log(matches)
```

However after adding the `/g` flags, the regex no longer returns anything but a `null`. Is it being used correctly as shown below?

```
    html = '<span><b>123</b>C / <b>456</b>K</span>'
    var matches = html.match('/<span><b>(.*?)</b>C / <b>(.*?)</b>K</span>/g')
    console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes from around the regex literal:

```
var matches = html.match(/<span><b>(.*?)<\/b>C \/ <b>(.*?)<\/b>K<\/span>/i);
```

When you use `'/<span><b>(.*?)</b>C / <b>(.*?)</b>K</span>/gi'` then literal string in the quote is used for matching.

Also you need to escape `/` and remove `g` to return all the matches.

It will return:

```
["<span><b>123</b>C / <b>456</b>K</span>", "123", "456"]
```

Comment: You should escape the tag closing `/` characters inside the expression. Answer is right if you add escaping.

Comment: @RaviH Thanks, that kind of works, but it only returns `[ '<span><b>123</b>C / <b>456</b>K</span>' ]`. Why does it not return `123` and `456`?

Comment: That is because your regex matches the whole string. Read more about javascript Regex API to know how to extract grouped values.

Comment: @Nyxynyx: I have updated the answer to return all the matches.